# Access to Path "something" is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, access-denied

Most of the solutions here don't work.

I am trying to upload a file, an image, to a folder in the server called images, when i click the button to upload it, after it passes `ImageUpload.SaveAs(Path)` i get an exception "Access to Path "any path here" is denied, now i tried editing the security tab of the folder and gave permission to `NETWORK SERVICE`, i tried giving permission to `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`, still not working. i also enabled ASP.NET Impersonation in the iis manager as some other people said, still same error.

Comment: You seem to have no idea what account used to store the images... Consider debugging and checking `Environment.UserName`. Add this information to the post...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The default Identity the applicationpool runs in, is the `ApplicationPoolIdentity`, not the `NETWORK SERVICE` account.

You could assign modify rights on the folder to the ApplicationPoolIdentity (look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account)), or you can change the identity of the application pool to a different user with permissions on the uploads folder.

Do take care when you run the applicationpool with a different user: make sure not to give that user more rights than in absolutely needs.